# How to set v-model dynamically in nested v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make a word search game using vue, and to make the grid I have done the following:

```
<table>
          <tr v-for="n in rows">
            <td v-for="i in cols" v-model="cols[n][i]">{{randomLetter()}}</td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to set the value for each td using v-model but my approach is not working to dynamically set the v-model.

Comment: ```
     <tr v-for="n in rows">
         <td v-for="i in cols" v-model="cells" :key="[n][i]">{{randomLetter()}}</td>
      </tr>
``` Is this the correct approach?

Comment: v-model only works on elements that emit an input event (vue 2) or update:modelValue event (vue 3).

Comment: @Bkedds First you have to understand the use of `v-model`, We basically use it for Form data bindings as it provides a two-way data binding. But in your case as `<td>` is just to show the data (one-way binding) There is no need to use `v-model` as from template user will not be able to change anything.